# How do I properly remove "Powered By Drupal"?

Tags: 7

How do I remove the "Powered By Drupal" string that is displayed on the site footer?

> [image: screenshot]

Does it involve PHP coding?

Answer (score 6):

Use this technique

go to yoursite/admin/structure/block

you will see the "Powered by Drupal" as a block

[image]

Choose - None - it will go away and you can create your own block with your own footer information

Answer (score 4):

Unset the "Powered by" block from the block admin (admin/structure/block). If the theme has hard-coded this, you'll have to remove it from the appropriate template.

Comment: Normally, that is a standard block Drupal core defines, but it could be as well hard-coded in a theme template, so +1 for mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

It is just like any other block on your website:

1) Hover over it, you will find a small settings icon will appear.

2) click on that and then configure block.

3) it will take you to the configuration page of that block.

4) from here you disable the block by change its region to none.

5) Save your block. Voila!

Comment: This requires the Contextual Links module to be enabled, which may not be the case depending on the profile chosen during install.